# How to fix hover dropdown menus on the navbar?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some work to set up a new website for a county, and these dropdown menus are giving me quite a bit of trouble. I'm using the code I have to make a custom theme for the county to use with Wordpress, though the issue I'm having pertains to the header specifically.

Issue: I have created three dropdown menus stemming from "Departments", "Services", and "How Do I". However, upon hovering over one of them, all three menus seem to conjoin into one and overlap each other. Also, the menu does not extend down past the navbar into the body, but creates a scroll option inside the navbar, which I do not want.

I've uploaded working chunks of HTML and CSS code to jsfiddle.net, so I'll share a link here: https://jsfiddle.net/cameoux/nbe18zav/

Feel free to take a look here though as well.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" style="color: #FFFFFF">
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>" alt="Image not found!" style="max-width: 100%; display: block;">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#howdoi" class="dropbtn">How Do I</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Lorem ipsum domat queri?</a>
          <a href="#">Lorem ipsum sumer dokar?</a>
          <a href="#">Lorem escat que poner populusque?</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#services" class="dropbtn">Services</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Pay Taxes Online</a>
          <a href="#">Voter Registration</a>
          <a href="#">Traffic Map</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#departments" class="dropbtn">Departments</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Chamber of Commerce</a>
          <a href="#">Health Department</a>
          <a href="#">Clerk's Office</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-bar">
      <a href="" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
```

```
.topnav {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-left: 7rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 15, 93, 0.85);
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav a,
.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover,
.dropbtn {
  color: rgba(213, 159, 15, 1.0);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12pt;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
```

Ideally, I'd like the menu items to line up vertically, for the dropdowns to extend past the navbar and into the body of the page, and for the menus to remain separate and not overlap. Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Isnt it because you created you wrote ".dropdown:hover .dropdown-content", so now it finds all the child elements with the class and shows them at once. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @KnucklePunch I created .dropdown:hover just to color the links I believe. Is there a way I can separate those child elements while only using one class for the contents of each dropdown? Or would it be better to create a new class for each one?

Comment: Ok, i deleted one asnwer.

From what I can see you did one mistake, that you enclosed all dropdowns into one <div> and when you hover over it you activate them all at once.

What you need to do is create it so that when you hover "Department,...", you show that one dropdown option.

Comment: @KnucklePunch They don't have links as of now since I haven't created pages for each yet, but I do plan to make each dropdown button a clickable link by using the <a> element.

Comment: @KnucklePunch Also, I believe you were correct with your initial advice, though I still need to figure out how to separate each menu.

Comment: I would fix it by enclosing all those pairs of elements of classes dropbtn and dropdown-content into each separate <div> with class dropdown. Maybe that would help.

Comment: @KnucklePunch Fantastic! That did it for the overlapping issue. Thanks. My only issues now are that my dropdown items are making a horizontal menu and that the dropdown boxes won't extend outside of and stop stretching the navbar down.

Comment: That is probably css, but I am no css wizard i use frameworks for this. Sorry cant help you there.